# Installing curl with ssl so I can install homebrew

Tags: ssl, curl, homebrew, ca

## The Solution

I used Bruno's post to find the solution, but feel that it needs to be made more concrete, so this is explicitly what I did.

1. Downloaded [cacert.pem](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) into my ~/.ssh dir (I don't know if this is where it should go, but I saw someone do something similar while trying to find a solution, so this is where I put it).
2. Set the env var CURL_CA_BUNDLE for the installation. This is actually solution number 4 from [the website](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) suggested by the failure. I just misunderstood what they were saying (a simple example might have saved me hours of confusion). Anyway, you'll need to specify the full path to the .pem file, then you can install like this `$ CURL_CA_BUNDLE=~/.ssh/cacert.pem ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"` And then it is installed!

---

## The Original Question

### How do I either

1. install homebrew, or
2. install curl with SSL so that I can install homebrew?

I'm on Mac OSX Leopard.

I'm trying to [install homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation), but I get the following error:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/Formula/...
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/...
==> The following directories will be made group writable:
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/local/share/man/man1
/usr/local/share/man/man3

Press enter to continue
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+w /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man3
==> Downloading and Installing Homebrew...
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). The default
 bundle is named curl-ca-bundle.crt; you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
/usr/bin/tar: Child returned status 1
/usr/bin/tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
Failed during: /bin/bash -o pipefail -c '/usr/bin/curl -sSfL https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master | /usr/bin/tar xz -m --strip 1'
```

I tried installing curl with macports and specifying +ssl, but that didn't work (sorry, I don't remember what the error was, and it took about an hour to get to that point, so I don't want to do it again). I uninstall the curl from macports and then run `$ whereis curl` which finds nothing.

So I go to [the site](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) suggested in the error message above. Most of the options don't seem applicable, but option 5 makes some sense:

> Get a better/different/newer CA cert bundle! 
>   One option is to extract the one a recent Firefox browser uses
>   by running 'make ca-bundle' in the curl build tree root

So I get the [curl source code](https://github.com/bagder/curl) and run `$ ./buildconf`, `$ ./configure`, `$ make`, `$ make ca-bundle`, and finally `$ sudo make install`. I check `$ whereis curl` and it says "/usr/bin/curl".

But when I run the homebrew install command again (in a new terminal window), I get the same error shown above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to recompile cURL, it already has SSL/TLS support, otherwise, it wouldn't display `error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`.

What you need is a bundle of CA certificates such as the server certificate of the server you're trying to talk to is issued by one of those CAs.

The cURL page you link from links to http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

You should be able to download the combined PEM bundle and use it. You could force it using `curl -fsSL --cacert /path/to/bundle.pem https://...` in the command above, or use `export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/path/to/bundle.pem` before running the command.

Normally, you'd need a way to trust what's inside this bundle, but there's always an element of "leap of faith" when it comes to importing commercial CAs (in the same way as they would be bundled for you with most browsers).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the original poster's solution didn't work for me. Even with the new CA bundle, I still had an SSL error during install:

> Failed during: /bin/bash -o pipefail -c '/usr/bin/curl -sSfL https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master | /usr/bin/tar xz -m --strip 1'

So instead of executing the install script directly, I first downloaded it, then added the `-k` switch (or `--insecure`) to it's curl command (found on line 126 in today's version), and then ran that patched install script.

First, update the curl bundle anyway, using [this method](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/6103#issuecomment-1694558), but with `curl` in case you don't have `wget`:

```
cd /usr/share/curl/
sudo curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o cacert.pem
sudo mv curl-ca-bundle.crt old.curl-ca-bundle.crt
sudo mv cacert.pem curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

Then go to https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation and copy the installer script link.

Get the installer script: (replace the URL with the current installer script URL)

```
curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731 -o homebrew-install.rb
```

Edit homebrew-install.rb: search for "curl" and add the -k switch

Finally, run your patched script:

```
ruby homebrew-install.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

the original directions work fine for me in OS X 10.9!
first download and *install XQuartz*

not sure why I need to place anything into ~/.ssh, but okay

System Preferences
  Sharing
  "Check" Remote Login
  "Click" + to add your user name
  then in xquartz type
  `ssh localhost
   answer yes to all
   type exit`

download the [pem file](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)
save to Downloads
in xquartz type

```
cd

cp Downloads/cacert.pem .ssh/cacert.pem
```

the pem file didn't complain that I needed to export the following worked fine

```
CURL_CA_BUNDLE=~/.ssh/cacert.pem

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

you'll be prompted to install if you have not installed Command line Utilities
click ok and follow prompts
there will be one prompt for YOUR Passsword type carefully and hit enter

```
brew doctor
brew update
brew doctor
brew search ssl
brew install openssl
```

"I as a front end UXD type person; happily surprised for no need to DL 2.09 GB xcode.app"

Answer (score 0):

ruby -e "$(curl -k -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
works because -k allows insecure SSL connections

Comment: the command is now
`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`